# How do I extract items out of a dictionary

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
"Player Details": {
    "Sally Smith": {
        "player_id": 2,
        "color_one": "blue",
        "color_two": "red"
    },
    "John Smith": {
        "player_id": 4,
        "color_one": "white",
        "color_two": "black"
    }
}
```

I need it to go into an array and end up like this:

```
"Player details": [
    {
        "player_id": "2",
        "color_one": "blue",
        "color_two": "red"
    },
    {
        "player_id": "4",
        "color_one": "white",
        "color_two": "black"
    }
]
```

I have tried the following, but the "value" still remains:

```
Object.entries(myDictionary).forEach(([key, value]) => {
   newArray.push({value})
});
```

I feel I am almost there, can anyone assist?

Comment: `{ 'Player Details' : Object.values(obj['Player Details']) }`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks, but can you elaborate, show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over `myDictionary["Player Details"]` and and push `value` into `newArray` instead of `{ value }`

or you could do it in one line using `Object.values`

```
Object.values(myDictionary["Player Details"])
```

```js
const myDictionary = {
  "Player Details": {
    "Sally Smith": {
        "player_id": 2,
        "color_one": "blue",
        "color_two": "red"
    },
    "John Smith": {
        "player_id": 4,
        "color_one": "white",
        "color_two": "black"
    }
  }
}

const newArray = [];

Object.entries(myDictionary["Player Details"]).forEach(([key, value]) => {
   newArray.push(value)
});

console.log(newArray);

// Or a single one liner

console.log(Object.values(myDictionary["Player Details"]));
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you!

Comment: Same idea, but I'd use something more compact: const newArray = [...Object.values(myDictionary["Player Details"])];

Answer (score 3):

Just get values from the object using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method which returns object property values in an array.

```js
let data = {
  "Player Details": {
    "Sally Smith": {
      "player_id": 2,
      "color_one": "blue",
      "color_two": "red"
    },
    "John Smith": {
      "player_id": 4,
      "color_one": "white",
      "color_two": "black"
    }
  }
}


let res = {
  'Player Details': Object.values(data['Player Details'])
};

// or in case you justt need the array then 
let res1 = Object.values(data['Player Details']);

console.log(res)
console.log(res1)
```

**FYI :** Since there is whitespace in your property you can't use [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) for accessing property instead of that use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

Comment: This works, but results in an object, whereas I need an array.

Comment: @user3328696  : `let res1 = Object.values(data['Player Details']);`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [**Object.values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
let obj = {"Player Details": {
    "Sally Smith": {
        "player_id": 2,
        "color_one": "blue",
        "color_two": "red"
    },
    "John Smith": {
        "player_id": 4,
        "color_one": "white",
        "color_two": "black"
    }
}}
let op = {'Player Details' : Object.values(obj['Player Details'])}

console.log(op)
```